# How can I display images (multimedia) from an EmailMessage?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, mime, mapi, exchangewebservices

I use Exchange Web Service Managed API to access my mailbox in the server. I can display the body of each EmailMessage, but if a message contains images I can't get them. I've heard about MIME but don't know how to use it, does someone know how MIME works in EWS MAPI?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

This is the code I use to acces EmailMessages:

```
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
            new ItemView(100));
        foreach (EmailMessage item in findResults.Items)
        {
            item.Load();
            if (!list.Contains(item.Id.UniqueId))
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["OutlookID"] = item.Id.UniqueId;
                dr["Onderwerp"] = item.Subject;
                dr["Omschrijving"] = item.Body;
                dr["Meldingsdatum"] = item.DateTimeSent;
                dr["Melder"] = ad.GetLoginName(item.Sender.Name);
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);


            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you have, you can access them in `item.Attachments`

Each image is an attachment.

Comment: this is the value I get: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AttachmentCollection

Comment: `foreach (var att in item.Attachments) Console.WriteLine (att.ContentLocation)` content location is an url to the attachment.

Comment: that's because the example code I provided `Console.WriteLine (att.ContentLocation)` doesn't do what you want to achieve. you will probably need to use a webRequest to get the item.

Comment: I know and I'm using a TextBox where I assign the att.ContentLocation-value

Comment: you can probably refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachment_members(v=exchg.80).aspx) for more info

Comment: if I do att.Name I can get the name of the files. But att.ContentLocation returns nothing :s